# How to load data into RecyclerView with Retrofit2 inAndroid

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-json, gson

I want load data from server and show into `recyclerView`, for connection i use `Retrofit2`. 
First i load **categoryData** and it's ok, i can see **categoryData**. but when click on category post i want load this post data into other activity but when go to this `activity` **NOT show data**!

I pass **postID** for for load this post and set this **postID** in `URL`.

With this code, i pass **postID** from **categoryAdapter** into `activity` with this code:

```
((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = holder.getPosition();
                R_CatModel model = mDateSet.get(pos);
                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), PostShow_page.class)
                        .putExtra("postID", model.getId())
```

**postShowActivity** `retrofit` **ApiInterface** :

```
@GET("api/get_post")
Call<R_PostModelResponse> getPostResponse(@Query("post_id") Integer id);
```

**postShowActivity codes:**

```
private void bindData() {

        // Setup Connect
        Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);
        Call<R_PostModelResponse> call = apiInterface.getPostResponse(postID);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<R_PostModelResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<R_PostModelResponse> call, Response<R_PostModelResponse> response) {

                if (response != null) {

                    models = response.body().getPost();

                    mAdaper = new CommentAdapter2(context, models);
                    Toast.makeText(PostShow_page.this, "GoTo Adapter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    comment_Recyclerview.setAdapter(mAdaper);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<R_PostModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**postShowAdapter code:**

```
public class CommentAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter2.ViewHolder> {

    private List<R_PostModel> mDataSet;
    private Context context;

    public CommentAdapter2(Context context,List<R_PostModel> mDataSet) {
        this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CommentAdapter2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CommentAdapter2.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        viewHolder.comment_name.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getComments().get(1).getCmName());
        viewHolder.comment_date.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getComments().get(4).getCmDate());
        viewHolder.comment_content.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getComments().get(3).getCmContent());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView comment_name, comment_content, comment_date;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            comment_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_userName_text);
            comment_content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_comment_text);
            comment_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_date_text);

        }
    }

}
```

**postDataModel:**

```
public class R_PostModel {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public Integer id;
    @SerializedName("type")
    public String type;
    @SerializedName("slug")
    public String slug;
    @SerializedName("url")
    public String url;
    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;
    @SerializedName("title_plain")
    public String title_plain;
    @SerializedName("content")
    public String content;
    @SerializedName("excerpt")
    public String excerpt;
    @SerializedName("date")
    public String date;
    @SerializedName("modified")
    public String modified;
    @SerializedName("comment_count")
    public int comment_count;
    @SerializedName("comment_status")
    public String comment_status;
    @SerializedName("comments")
    public List<R_PostComment> comments;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getSlug() {
        return slug;
    }

    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle_plain() {
        return title_plain;
    }

    public void setTitle_plain(String title_plain) {
        this.title_plain = title_plain;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getExcerpt() {
        return excerpt;
    }

    public void setExcerpt(String excerpt) {
        this.excerpt = excerpt;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    public void setModified(String modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    public int getComment_count() {
        return comment_count;
    }

    public void setComment_count(int comment_count) {
        this.comment_count = comment_count;
    }

    public String getComment_status() {
        return comment_status;
    }

    public void setComment_status(String comment_status) {
        this.comment_status = comment_status;
    }

    public List<R_PostComment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(List<R_PostComment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
```

**postShowModelResponse:**

```
public class R_PostModelResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;
    @SerializedName("post")
    public List<R_PostModel> post;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<R_PostModel> getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(List<R_PostModel> post) {
        this.post = post;
    }
}
```

**Same json:**

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "post": {
        "id": 2289,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "11",
        "url": "http:\/\/site.com\/1393\/02\/12\/11\/",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Donec tempus urna risus",
        "title_plain": "Donec tempus urna risus",
        "content": "<p class=\"big\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet neque vitae mauris. Etiam malesuada ultricies. Nullam ut nunc odio eget volutpat a, rutrum ac, magna. Nulla facilisi. Nullam justo. Sed leo tristique senectus et ultrices sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing ornare. Nullam vulputate luctus. Nulla interdum libero. Maecenas tincidunt. Pellentesque dolor. In urna. Suspendisse sollicitudin. Vestibulum tempus purus fermentum imperdiet tincidunt, risus pede, luctus laoreet. Aenean ac eros quis eleifend congue. Nam dolor eget velit. Suspendisse at<\/p>\n<div class=\"column one-third\"><div class=\"quick_fact animate-math\"><div class=\"number-wrapper\"><span class=\"number\" data-to=\"35\">35<\/span><\/div><h3 class=\"title\">countries<\/h3><hr class=\"hr_narrow\" \/><div class=\"desc\">Donec vestibulum justo a diam ultricies pel lentesque. Quisque mattis diam vel lac.<\/div><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"column one-third\"><div class=\"quick_fact animate-math\"><div class=\"number-wrapper\"><span class=\"number\" data-to=\"142\">142<\/span><\/div><h3 class=\"title\">articles<\/h3><hr class=\"hr_narrow\" \/><div class=\"desc\">Donec vestibulum justo a diam ultricies pel lentesque. Quisque mattis diam vel lac.<\/div><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"column one-third\"><div class=\"quick_fact animate-math\"><div class=\"number-wrapper\"><span class=\"number\" data-to=\"89\">89<\/span><\/div><h3 class=\"title\">projects<\/h3><hr class=\"hr_narrow\" \/><div class=\"desc\">Donec vestibulum justo a diam ultricies pel lentesque. Quisque mattis diam vel lac.<\/div><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"hr_dots\" style=\"margin: 0 auto 30px;\"><span><\/span><span><\/span><span><\/span><\/div>\n\n<p>Praesent odio ac turpis luctus eu, ornare varius, leo. Suspendisse sed metus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per inceptos hymenaeos. Sed sed est. Sed venenatis. Morbi tincidunt. Nullam justo. Vestibulum ut justo a odio. Etiam et pede eget metus nonummy at, rhoncus dolor in interdum pellentesque quis, lacinia aliquet. In mauris sit amet leo. Aliquam erat consectetuer vestibulum varius. Cras ut orci at lorem odio tellus hendrerit sed, congue fringilla.<\/p>\n<p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per inceptos hymenaeos. Maecenas vehicula, dui nulla, egestas sodales, augue commodo nec, ullamcorper ligula lorem odio sit amet, vestibulum wisi ultricies eu, magna. Fusce aliquet elit, gravida tellus tristique eget, porta eget, eros. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin cursus magna. Sed placerat. Mauris vel risus. Nunc accumsan dictum, laoreet viverra. Cras tempus purus at risus auctor tincidunt. Sed sed tortor. In venenatis consequat. Donec iaculis. Curabitur est pretium wisi, sed leo. Sed tincidunt risus neque ultrices consectetuer. Etiam mollis ut, dolor. Maecenas.<\/p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>Donec tempus, urna risus nec mauris. Lorem ipsum primis in nulla ac arcu vitae augue. Vivamus nec elit a dui. Morbi id leo nec dui. Maecenas.<\/p>\n",
        "date": "\u06f1\u06f3\u06f9\u06f3-\u06f0\u06f2-\u06f1\u06f2 \u06f0\u06f9:\u06f3\u06f8:\u06f3\u06f1",
        "modified": "2014-05-02 09:38:31",
        "comments": [{
            "id": 10,
            "name": "&#1605;&#1581;&#1605;&#1583;",
            "url": "",
            "date": "2016-09-28 00:00:00",
            "content": "<p>&#1578;&#1587;&#1578; &#1662;&#1610;&#1575;&#1605; &#1575;&#1586; &#1587;&#1605;&#1578; &#1576;&#1585;&#1606;&#1575;&#1605;&#1607; &#1606;&#1608;&#1610;&#1587;&#1610;<\/p>\n",
            "parent": 0
        }, {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Mohammad1",
            "url": "",
            "date": "2016-09-28 00:00:00",
            "content": "<p>Test Comment 1<\/p>\n",
            "parent": 0
        }, {
```

For test i insert `Toast` message in **postShowActivity** `retrofit` response, but **not show this `Toast`**!

```
Toast.makeText(PostShow_page.this, "GoTo Adapter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Update :** 
When running application, not calling onResponse, calling onFailure!

How can i fix this problem and show data?

Comment: try to debug and check whether it is calling onResponse or onFailure

Comment: @Manifest, I test it, calling onFailure

Comment: @Manifest, can you help me my friend? i really need this

Comment: @Manifest, thank you my bro, I will wait

Comment: @Kmh54: Check the response you got from retrofit, may be some issue in json parsing thats why it cannot parse in R_PostModelResponse.

Comment: @ManishJain, I think my problem is `PostModelRefrense`! because in my `json`, post is not Array! but in `ModelResponse` and `onResponce` (from `retrofit`) i initialize `List<R_PostModel>`

Comment: @ManishJain, can you go to chat and invite me? please

Comment: @Manifest, why not send me chat list? :(

Comment: @Manifest, can you send me your email address? or i send email and your replay it. just help me my bro. it's very important for me :(

Comment: @Manifest, thank you my bro, do you have teamviewer for see codes and chat ?

Comment: @Kmh54, your json above in `post` is an object not array. If your onResponse from retrofit get an array, I think you sample data above wrong.

Comment: @RoShanShan, yes my bro i know this. but when remove List<> show me error. in activity and adapter. how can i fix it?

Comment: @Kmh54, Did you test your api result?

Comment: @RoShanShan, do you have teamviewer? please

Comment: I think you should use **Postman** to test your api, after that post your result from api. We will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to change your `R_PostModelResponse` by this :

```
public class R_PostModelResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;
    @SerializedName("post")
    public R_PostModel post;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public R_PostModel getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(R_PostModel post) {
        this.post = post;
    }
}
```

Now, please change your `CommentAdapter2` class by this :

```
public class CommentAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter2.ViewHolder> {

    private R_PostModel mDataSet;
    private Context context;

    public CommentAdapter2(Context context,R_PostModel mDataSet) {
        this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CommentAdapter2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CommentAdapter2.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        viewHolder.comment_name.setText(mDataSet.getComments().get(1).getCmName());
        viewHolder.comment_date.setText(mDataSet.getComments().get(4).getCmDate());
        viewHolder.comment_content.setText(mDataSet.getComments().get(3).getCmContent());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView comment_name, comment_content, comment_date;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            comment_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_userName_text);
            comment_content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_comment_text);
            comment_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_date_text);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When update my codes, with your code show me error in `models = response.body().getPost();` because this is list. and when delete this list show me error in adapter!

Comment: actually the problem is you are treating **"post": {}** as a list like this **"post": [{}]**, but in your real json response it is an object **"post": {}**. Now either you have to change your **JSON Response** such that it would contain **post** like a list ("post": [{}]) OR you have to change your `models` from **list** to simple `R_PostModel` object.

Comment: Thanks but i am amateur :( i remove List<> from model show me many error! do you have Teamviewer? for see my codes? please bor

Comment: Can you help me Rahul?

Comment: Thanks, with this your code calling onResponse. but just show 1 post! in json i see 10 post, but in application just shoe 1post!!!! how can i fix it?

Comment: can you give me whole json response, because it is all about that data, by which we can code proper.

Comment: You write     `@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1;
    }` , i think for this just show 1 post!

Comment: You need my json?

Comment: yep bro, i need it otherwise i may not be able to solve your problem

Comment: if your "Previous activity" contains a list of posts than why are you displaying list of posts again when you click on any post from "Previous activity". It will simply show the post details, as happening right now. Bro i'm getting confused about your requirements.

Comment: Rahul do you have TeamViewer my bro?

Comment: No bro i don't have access for teamviewer, try to solve it by yourself, may be it is just a simple issue to resolve :)

Comment: Ok my bro, can you go to StachOverFlow chat for this post and invite me?

Comment: Can you going to chat? for solve this problem i have a idea, but i don't know how can i it

Comment: Bro currently i do not have that much reputation that is needed to create a room for chat on stack overflow :(

Comment: I am really bad lucky :( i just problem with this :(

Comment: Hey, check your mail, ive sent you an email on that.

Comment: Thanks Rahul <3 . your email receive :D . i accept your answer and going speak in email . yahoo chat or Gmail chat :D

Comment: ok bro, i'll try to resolve your issue as per your requirements.